# Can I sort all functions in my dart project?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

We can sort dart functions by VSCode settings: `"source.sortMembers": "explicit"`

But when I want to sort members for all my dart files in `lib`, what should I do?

Is `source.sortMembers` sort functions by some opened code? Maybe I can clone it to sort all my members that in my project.

I have to maintain an old project, the members in class of the project was unsorted, I want to sort all members in each file of the project.

thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to maintain an old project, the members in class of the project was unsorted, I want to sort all members in each file of the project.